# bash prefix output with current directory

Tags: linux, bash, build

After a couple of hours of flailing, I give up.

I have a long-running build script in a bash function, let's call it "Build":

```
function Build( ) {
    cd /plugins
    make
    cd /acc
    make
}
```

... and I would like the output from the script to be prefixed on each line with the current directory, something like:

```
/plugins:   configure:  checking for gcc
/plugins/inner:   making inner modules
...
/acc:       configure: checking for speed of strstr.
/acc/misc   making misc pieces
```

.... and so on.  There are dozens of "cd"s in the scripts so I don't want to change each and every one.   Tried various combinations of piping to awk and trap DEBUG, but no joy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding built-in `cd` with function like:

```
cd(){ builtin cd "$@"; pwd }
```

Or if you really want to instrument every command, then:

```
trap "eval 'echo -n $PWD:'" DEBUG
```

Or to trace really every `chdir` syscall even inside the child processes of the actual bash script (e.g. `make`), you can use `strace`:

```
strace -f -e trace=chdir bash build.sh
```

Comment: Tried those.  the cd() function only traps cd's that are explicitly in the script, not ones in makefiles.

Comment: Tried those.  the cd() function only traps cd's that are explicitly in the script, not ones in makefiles.  The DEBUG trap only echoes the value of PWD, not the current result of executing pwd.  Plus it only seems to trap commands in the main script, not any spun-off makefiles.    Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot trace chdirs inside the make process from the bash script. However, you can try setting environment variable `MAKEFLAGS=-w` so that make will trace the chdirs it self.
But if you really want to trace all `chdir` syscalls from any process, then I guess `strace` or similar hack with LD_PRELOADed c-library is the way to go.